# Is there any equivalent to always true lambda expression?

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, equivalent

I'm using a series of commands called RelayCommand which have a function to execute and a function that  returns a bool telling whether or not you can execute the first function. The fact is that I'm using the lambda expression () => true most of the time. Is there any expression that I can use to make it more readable? Like System.TrueFunction or something similar.

See it in context:

```
  this.PasteFromExcelCommand = new RelayCommand(PasteFromExcel, this.OneRowSelected);
  this.SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SaveSession, CanSave);
  this.SwitchViewCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SwitchView, () => true);
  this.ExitCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Exit, () => true);
```

Comment: Do you have the source for the RelayCommand? Have you tried passing `null`? My implementation always returns true if i pass `null`.

Comment: Sometimes the second parameter is even optionally and will always return true if it's not set.

Comment: I haven't thought on that. RelayCommand is part of my project so can implement a one argument version that defaults to return true. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your own

```
static readonly Func<bool> TrueFunc = () => true;
```

And use it like this

```
new RelayCommand(this.Exit, TrueFunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in, but you can easily create your own:

```
public bool TrueFunc()
{
  return true;
}

this.ExitCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Exit, TrueFunc);
```